# Meaning of cocycle on a spectrum?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, spectra

What is the meaning of the notation $Z^{p}(F,\mathbb{R})$ where $F$ is a spectrum ?
I encountered this in a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1143642908) (see the line after remark 4.49) that I am reading, but can not understand the meaning. I tried googling, but to no avail. Thanks

Comment: In Definition 4.32 they define a complex $C^*(F,A)$ for any spectrum $F$ and abelian group $A$. Then $Z^*(F,A)$ is the collection of its cocycles. What these look like is explained immediately after that definition.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thanks so much ! My bad, I should have known. Very embarrassing for me.